# Animation on the ItemsSource binding on a ListView

Tags: xaml, listview, winrt-xaml

I have a Universal App solution and on the Windows project I'm using a master-detail view similar to the split-page template. ListView on the left with the items and ListView on the right with the items details.

The binding from the second ListView is done through

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Stages, ElementName=itemListView}"
```

and it works perfectly, when changing selected items (itemListView is the name of the first ListView).

The **problem** I'm having is with the animation the 2nd ListView does when I select an item with a bigger list of details, let's say from 5 to 8.

When I select the item with the 8 "details", 3 items are added to the end of the ListView on the right and the first 5 swap out (by fading and moving to the right) with the new 5 **half a second later**. This looks odd and the visual effect is not pleasent.

The same thing happens when changing to a list with fewer items: the last 3 are immediately removed and the remaining 5 fade away to the new ones, but this effect is not that prominent.

Is there anything I can do?

**Update**

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YYZQWsvAlCg)

Comment: Hard to visualize your issue just by description. Can you provide some xaml or maybe something simpler that reproduces the issue so we can see what you're seeing too?

Comment: Updated the post with the video link at the bottom.

Comment: So is it actually 3 listviews with 2 stacked on top of another on the right?

Comment: No, like I said in the post it's the template from the split-view page that comes with VS. ListView on the left with items and when I chose one the ListView on the right gets filled through the databinding statement in the post, but it produces that effect when filling with more items than before.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand why 3 of them seem to be static and the rest act as actual items, that's weird, may help more to show some code amigo

Comment: There really is no more code, just the first list: `<ListView
                Header="Packages"
                x:Name="itemListView"
                MinWidth="250"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Packages}"
                IsSwipeEnabled="False"
                IsItemClickEnabled="False"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PackageItemTemplate}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}"
                SelectionChanged="PackageSelected_Event">
            </ListView>`

The second ListView is similar but with that binding in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable ListViewItems animations all you need to do is clear `TransitionCollection` 
or declare it in xaml as empty:

```
<ListView>
 <ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
  <TransitionCollection />
 </ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
<ListView>
```

Comment: Great, that stopped the weird effect in the video. Still can't understand why only some items in the list were affected.Thank you